# Elastic Search fulltext Search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-analyzers

I save the content of two PDF Documents in the Elastic Search.
The direction is _source.attachment.content and I want to make a full text search.

Now I have two different PDF's in my Elastic Search 2 which contain the word: "Overview" and others without this word.

I search for it like this:

```
GET _search
{ 
   "_source":[ 
      "attachment.*",
      "meta.*"
   ],
   "query":{ 
      "bool":{ 
         "must":[ 
            { 
               "multi_match":{ 
                  "query":"Over",
                  "fuzziness":2
               }
            },
            { 
               "match":{ 
                  "meta.teamId":"specific id"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

As a result I get one of the two documents, and a lot of other documents without the substring "over" in it. If I type "overv" no documents containing this substring are being returned as result. If I type "overview" then I find only the two documents I want to have.

Is there something I can make better?

Thank you in advance

Edit:
the hit looks like:

```
{
        "_index" : "docs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "UO8RI28B94W61yv-lXqW",
        "_score" : 16.099525,
        "_source" : {
          "attachment" : {
            "date" : "2019-12-20T11:28:13Z",
            "content_type" : "application/pdf",
            "language" : "et",
            "title" : "Microsoft Word - Dokument1",
            "content" : """
Test    PDF 

2345    

Etwas   

Overview
""",
            "content_length" : 42
          },
          "meta" : {
            "teamId" : "specific id"
          }
        }
      }
```

here is the mapping:

```
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "attachment" : {
      "properties" : {
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "contentId" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
    "meta" : {
      "properties" : {
        "teamId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "teamId" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share mapping of your index and some sample doc and example output on these docs

Comment: @OpsterESNinja I edit something. Do you mean this?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for info,i will look into it

Comment: @OpsterESNinja do you habe any idea?

Comment: Still I don't see the sample documents, also please make sure you format your question well and steps are clear so that we can reprduce your issue and help you :)

Comment: one more thing, can you please comment on whether you tried the existing answer and if it doesn't work then what is the reason, please follow-up on your questions so that community knows the latest status

Comment: How can I upload the documents here?

Comment: I meant the payload of your index API

Comment: any update here?

Comment: can you give me an example for a payload? In the moment I don't know what you mean. Do you mean docs/_doc ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to index your data using nGram tokenizer (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

You can read more here - https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch

Comment: you need to index youur data using ngram tokenizer. Basically while storing in elasticsearch it will store all combinations so while doing query, you can search on incomplete words as well.

Comment: If i try this, i always become errors like "Id is already existing"